# Jquery id returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

I am trying to get id of a selected row in a table.

The rows are generated based on number of objects in `foodList` (JSP page).

**JSP Code**

```
<tbody>
  <c:forEach items="${foodList}" var="det">
    <tr class="clickable-row">
      <td class="pt-0 pb-0"><button id="${det.b_No}" style="font-size:8px" class="btn btn-danger delete btn-sm pt-1 pb-1 mb-0" data-title="Delete"></button></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="${det.wt}" /></td>
  </c:forEach>

  </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$('#table_id').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  alert($(this).find(".pt-0").html());
  alert($(this).find(".pt-0").attr("id"));
});
```

First alert is displaying the text as follows which is as expected,

```
<button id="1015" style="font-size:8px" class="btn btn-danger delete btn-sm pt-1 pb-1 mb-0" data-title="Delete"></button>
```

But for the second alert I am expecting the id (1015) but showing as "`undefined`".

Comment: As you can see  td with class `.pt-0` has no id. The button as td's child has that one.You have either change html code and set id for `td` element or change javascript code to smth like `.find(".pt-0 button")`

Comment: `<td class="pt-0 pb-0">` has no `id` attribute, the code is working fine

Comment: Hi Banzay,Clive thanks for reply. It was a mistake.  .find(".pt-0 button") is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the id is in button element so use :

```
alert($(this).find(".pt-0").find("button").attr("id"));
```

or simply direct access

```
alert($(this).find(".pt-0 button").attr("id"));
```

See below snippet :

```js
$('#table').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
  alert($(this).find(".pt-0").html());
  alert($(this).find(".pt-0 button").attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr class="clickable-row">
    <td class="pt-0 pb-0"><button id="1508" style="font-size:8px" class="btn btn-danger delete btn-sm pt-1 pb-1 mb-0" data-title="Delete">del</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```